# Issue with eros_python_tools and roscreate-qt-ros-pkg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble with roscreate-qt-ros-pkg. I cannot manage to get it working. I got the package eros_python_tools as per [these](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools#) instructions; however, upon running the command to make a qt package, I get the following:

```
allenh1@allenh1-U50F:~/ros_workspace$ roscreate-qt-ros-pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allenh1/ros_workspace/eros_python_tools/scripts/roscreate-qt-ros-pkg", line 3, in <module>
    from ros import eros_python_tools
ImportError: cannot import name eros_python_tools
```

Did I do something wrong in my .bashrc or my setup.sh file?

Thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31304/issue-with-eros_python_tools-and-roscreate-qt-ros-pkg/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-04-05**:
Which ros version are you using (i.e. diamondback, electric, fuerte)?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-04-06**:
I am using fuerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eros is still catching up (due to the big change in build environment over electric and fuerte).

The same tools have migrated to [qt_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_ros). If you're on ubuntu, just

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-qt-ros
```

and follow the instructions on the roswiki.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on 2012-12-16**:
Hi, I am not trying to run roscreate-qt-pkg but I can into the same error with rostoolchain. I did install ros-fuerte-qt-ros but now I can't find rostoolchain. Did that get installed?

**Comment by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on 2012-12-16**:
Hi, I am not trying to run roscreate-qt-pkg but I can into the same error with rostoolchain. I did install ros-fuerte-qt-ros but now I can't find rostoolchain. Did that get installed?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-02-21**:
rostoolchain was in the old eros system. Your best bet is to upgrade to groovy and get familiar with catkin. That makes the cross compiling process natural (wrt cmake processes).